# Logstash index based on filter

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

Hi I am reading stdout and filtering both apache and application logs using logstash as below

```
input {
 beats {
 port => 5044
 }
}
filter {
  grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
  }
  json {
   source => "message"
  }
}
output { elasticsearch { hosts => "http://elasticsearch-master:9200"} }
```

These logs are reaching the elastic search properly, however how can i give a seperate index in es for apache and application log in logstash output here?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate those in input plugin by using "type" . you can try the below
**Note**: Assuming that the log is apache logs

```
input {
 beats {
 port => 5044
#assuming that your log is apache
 type => "apache" 
 }
}


filter {
  grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
  }
  json {
   source => "message"
  }
}



output {  
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}


    if [type] == "apache" {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => "http://elasticsearch-master:9200"  
            index => "apache_index"   
        }
    } 

    else {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => "http://elasticsearch-master:9200"  
            index => "application_index"   
        }
    }
}
```

Keep Posted !!! Thanks !!!

Comment: thanks..both my application logs and apache logs are coming together from same beats. Will this seperate them and send to different indexes?

Comment: do you mean to say that both the logs are from same file?

Comment: yes sir they both log to /var/log/containers/*.log which is read by filebeats

Comment: could you share few lines of that logs which has both apache and application log